# How to check iOS version delphi xe5/xe6

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Is there a way to check the iOS version within a Delphi app? I would like to create specific piece of code for iOS7 and iOS6 in Delphi XE6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [TOSVersion](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion) record in System.SysUtils.

```
if TOSVersion.Check(7, 0) then //Os is iOS 7
```

Also you can find sample for iOS [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles).

Comment: there should be a platform check too, either using `{$IFDEF IOS}` or `if TOSVersion.Check(7, 0) and (TOSVersion.Platform = pfiOS)`